# Use pymc model to generate predictions on new data

Tags: python, pymc

Coming from a typical machine learning perspective, it's common to think of two phases in modeling: training and scoring. I'd like to achieve something similar using `pymc`, but I'm finding it very difficult.

Consider something simple, such as a linear regression. I have an input data matrix `X` and a target vector `y`. Maybe I add some new additional variables to `X` via a deterministic function so that `X_det` is a deterministic variable. As is typically done, we define a deterministic `y_hat`, which combines the coefficients `b` and data `X_det`, and stochastic observed variable `Y_obs`:

```
@pymc.deterministic
def y_hat(b=b, X=X_det):
    return np.dot(X, b)

Y_obs = pymc.Normal(name='Y', mu=y_hat, tau=tau, value=y, observed=True)
```

I can also add a simulation variable to conveniently capture the predicted posterior:

```
Y_sim = pymc.Normal(name='Y_sim', mu=y_hat, tau=tau)
```

I can easily create the model for this, run MCMC to get posteriors on the coefficients `b` and predictions `Y_sim`.

But is there an easy way for me to generate a predicted posterior for *new* (i.e. not used in the inference) predictor data, say `X_test`? As I understand it, you can probably achieve this by using `numpy.ma.MaskedArray`, where you concatenate `X` and `X_test` (call this `X_concat`) and concatenate `y` with some dummy values to match the length of `X_concat`, and mask the dummy values. However, this feels clunky and requires a fixed `X_test`. If I want to score `X_test2`, I would have to run MCMC sampling all over again. This feels like overkill since you already have the trace data.

I guess what I'm searching for is some kind of function associated with a `pymc.Model` that takes values for stochastic variables and returns the values of deterministic variables. Maybe something along the lines of

```
model = pymc.Model([X_det, Y_obs, Y_sim, b, y_hat, tau, ...])
mcmc = pymc.MCMC(model)

# Score new data:
y_predicted = model.magic_function(X_test, mcmc.trace)
```

This is analogous to the `predict` function available to `sklearn` regressors. It seems like in principle this should be possible and not too difficult, but for the life of me I can't find a nice way to achieve this. But I'm assuming this situation comes up quite frequently. Does anyone have thoughts or suggestions?

Comment: If I understand your question, `np.dot(X_test, trace['b'])` gives you want you want. In other words, you're using your training data to get the posteriors of the model coefficients, and then you use those same posteriors to predict against new data.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @inversion. Unfortunately, it's not quite so simple for me. I have several additional variables constructed from the input predictor variables (`X` or `X_train`). These variables are implemented as various deterministic variables. So there's not a single function for me to call. I would essentially need to define every derived variable twice: once as a deterministic variable and once as a parameterized function. I'm looking to avoid this.

Comment: But don't you use the same construction method using the new input for your deterministic variables?

Comment: i.e., you use the same construction method using the new input for your deterministic variables. For example,

`y_pred = a(X_test) * np.dot(X_test, trace['b'])`

where `a` is just a deterministic function of `X_test` and `b` is the posterior of your parameters.

You're right. There isn't a single function to call, like in `sklearn`.